# 1064 mysql error when using @

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am recieving this mysql error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@password)' at line 1

This is for the sql below:

```
Update Teacher 
SET TeacherSalt=@salt, TeacherPassword=SHA1(TeacherSalt @password)
```

What do I need to change so this sql could work?

UPDATE:

Need helping salting the PAssword. If the TeacherPassword and TeacherSalt columns look like this:

```
TeacherPassword     TeacherSalt

cricket01
sachin01
priggy02
```

Then after I do this statement:

```
Update Teacher 
SET    TeacherSalt = @salt, 
       TeacherPassword = SHA1(CONCAT(@password,@salt))
```

Then the TeacherPassword and TeacherSalt columns both provide blank rows. How can I successfully salt the passwords?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: try CONCAT to salt and password. And reply to favoretti: it's irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it like this? (*remove the column `TeacherSalt` in the `SHA1`*)

```
Update Teacher 
SET    TeacherSalt = @salt, 
       TeacherPassword = SHA1(CONCAT(@password,@salt))
```

## [*SQLFiddle Example*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e61f/3)

Comment: Hi, can I ask a quick question, your answer has solved the error, but it does not salt the password, instead both the TeacherPAssword and TeacherSalt columns become blank after the update. How do I salt the password correctly? IS it simple or complex?

Comment: hello, if you want to salt the password, you need to caoncatenate it with the salt. you can read more on this link :) http://onelastbit.com/?p=138 thank you..

Comment: I tried your answer but I still have blank columns for the password and salt. Am I suppose to include your answer statmeent and then include the first code snippet from the article you sent me?

Comment: are you sure you have supplied values for `@password` and `@salt`? kindly see the example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e61f/3

Comment: DO I need to do this `Update Teacher SET TeacherSalt=@salt, TeacherPassword=SHA1(Salt @password)
`

Comment: you can't do that. you will get a syntax error if you do that. `SHA( )` accepts only one parameter that's why you need to concatenate your `@password` and `@salt` values..

Comment: So how do I get random strings to be include in TeacherSalt column?

Comment: this code produces 10-character random string: `SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()), -10)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax is off, you have an extra `TeacherSalt` in the `Password` field:

```
Update Teacher 
SET TeacherSalt=@salt, TeacherPassword=SHA1(@password)
```

Based on your comment it sounds like you want this:

```
Update Teacher 
SET TeacherSalt=@salt, TeacherPassword=SHA1(CONCAT(@password,@salt))
```

Comment: Hi, can I ask a quick question, your answer has solved the error, but it does not salt the password, instead both the TeacherPAssword and TeacherSalt columns become blank after the update. How do I salt the password correctly? IS it simple or complex?

Comment: John Totet Woo provided same answer as well. I will edit question so you can see what is happening give me 5 mins :)

Comment: I will update question so you can see what is happening but I don't think I included any values for `@password` and `@salt`.

Comment: DO I need to do this `Update Teacher SET TeacherSalt=@salt, TeacherPassword=SHA1(Salt @password)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you need to concatenate the strings.

```
Update Teacher  
SET TeacherSalt=@salt, TeacherPassword=SHA1(@salt + @password)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to glue salt and password. So for example:

```
UPDATE Teacher 
SET TeacherSalt = @salt, TeacherPassword = SHA1(CONCAT(@salt, @password))
```